Ошибка при запуске проекта на Nuxt 3 ERROR [worker reload] [worker init]
Ошибка возникает при запуске проекта, появляется только на моей машине(windows 11), на других компах и системах все в порядке, если удалить поле "type":"module" из package.json, то все запускается без проблем
проект перенесен на ESM(import/export)
npm config prefix написан в формате file:///path/to/file(хотя менял как угодно - не влияет)
nodejs 20.18.0 (пробовал переустанавливать, чистить кэш и тп)
глобально установлены только eslint, sass, scss
i Purgecss is not enabled! Likely because you are in dev mode                                                                                          nuxt:tailwindcss 20:22:52
ℹ Using default Tailwind CSS file                                                                                                                     nuxt:tailwindcss 20:22:52
ℹ Tailwind Viewer: https://localhost.********.ru:/_tailwind/                                                                                         nuxt:tailwindcss 20:22:53
✔ Vite client built in 82ms                                                                                                                                            20:22:54
✔ Vite server built in 2138ms                                                                                                                                          20:22:56
✔ Nuxt Nitro server built in 7376 ms                                                                                                                             nitro 20:23:06
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 0ms                                                                                                                                         20:23:06   

[20:23:06]  ERROR  [worker reload] [worker init] Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:'

  at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/load:249:11)
  at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:130:3)
  at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:555:13)
  at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:56)
  at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:71:27)
  at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:447:17)
  at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:259:34)
  at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:17)
  at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:21)

ℹ Vite server warmed up in 7760ms 

так же в инете пишут, что проблема бывает из-за модуля @nuxt/robots, в проекте его нет

конкретно в моем случае, нашелся файлик с импортом "path/to/file.js", убрал ".js" - все стало норм
